# Unable to target Mura Form

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, mura

Unable to target the build-in Mura form using Jquery.

The following is the code:

```
$("#field-whatisyourcurrentplan").on('change',function(){
          var ident = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");
              console.log(ident);

          switch (ident){
            case "field-26dee5f9-5c7c-476a-a7d1-54d826943efa":
                console.log("Other selected")
            break;
          }
        });
```

I was able to find documentation in 7.1 where their is a built in feature to have the script to run at the same time as the Mura form is open [Mura Documentation](https://docs.getmura.com/v7-1/mura-developers/mura-rendering/murajs/forms-mura-js/). However, the version of Mura I am running is in 6.2.

Per my understanding, I should be able to just include my function into the page do to the form is not rendered asynchronously. However, when I do just include my code, nothing happens. When I insert my code in the console, it works fine.

My question is: How can I run my function in the Mura site manager, where the page resides?

Comment: Is your jQuery code waiting to run until the document is fully loaded? Is your code in `$( document ).ready()`

Comment: @Miguel-F: No it is not.

Comment: Is there feature in 6.2 that is similar to Mura 7.1

Comment: Not that I am aware of. But you should be able to roll your own jQuery to have similar functionality. Did you try placing your code within `$( document ).ready()`? What happened when you did?

Comment: @Miguel-F: Yes and it still did not work

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: @Miguel-F: Nothing happens. My script does work when I copy and paste the code in the console.

Comment: @INSGUEST Have you tried with Mura 6.2 docs? You may got solution here refer this URL https://docs.getmura.com/v6/front-end/lab-exercises/jquery-uniform/